# How to fix the error when download stock price using tq_get in r?

Tags: r, finance, stock, yahoo-finance, quantmod

I'm trying to use tq_get to download the stock prices based on the tickers. Here is the head of my dataset `merge_df`. I have more than 300 companies and I need to get their stock price the day before the date.filed.

| symbol | company_name | date.filed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Agilent Technologies | 2020-12-18 |
| A | Agilent Technologies | 2019-12-19 |
| A | Agilent Technologies | 2021-12-17 |
| AA | Alcoa | 2020-02-21 |
| AA | Alcoa | 2019-02-26 |
| AA | Alcoa | 2021-02-25 |

Here I want to thank to @Tom Hoel who provided one of the solution to me. But when I tried this code, I found it only works when there is only one date for one company.
Here is the code:

```
final_df <- merge_df %>%  
  mutate(date.filed = date.filed %>% as.Date(), 
         price_before_filing = map2(.x = symbol, 
                                    .y = date.filed, 
                                    ~ tq_get(.x, from = as.Date(.y) - 1) %>% 
                                      slice(1) %>% 
                                      pull(adjusted)) %>% 
           as.numeric()) %>% 
  select(symbol, company_name, price_before_filing, everything())
```

The error reported as:

```
Warning: Problem with `mutate()` column `price_before_filing`.
ℹ `price_before_filing = `%>%`(...)`.
ℹ x = 'BAND', get = 'stock.prices': Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "BAND", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE, : Unable to import “BAND”.
BAND download failed after two attempts. Error message:
HTTP error 401.

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `price_before_filing`.
ℹ `price_before_filing = `%>%`(...)`.
x no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "logical"
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Do anyone know why I have this error and how can I fix it?

Much thanks!!

Comment: Is it only the ticker `BAND` that causes an error? What is the filing date on that company, I might need to troubleshoot that specific case

Comment: Hi Tom, I've shared the dataset with you via google drive. The tickers are correct and I can found them through yahoo finance and my packages are updated but the error is still there.

Comment: I don't know whats wrong, I ran the same code on your `merge_df1.csv` and got the expected output with prices one day prior to the filing date. Maybe try to run the code on another machine?

Comment: Hi Tom, you didn't have any errors while downloading those prices? I tried another machine but every time I ran the code, there are some other companies has the same errors besides BAND

Comment: I only ran for some the tickers, but after inspecting ... `BF.B` is not recognised by tidyquant. And the package fails when you query that many times at once. The dataset is too big. You might need to do it in multiple session, taking 1:500 at once maybe. Also, weed out the tickers that are not recognised.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I do not get any errors. Are your packages up to date?
I am running `tidyquant 1.0.4` and `tidyverse 1.3.1`

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  mutate(date.filed = date.filed %>% as.Date(), 
         price_before_filing = map2(.x = symbol, 
                             .y = date.filed, 
                             ~ tq_get(.x, 
                                      from = as.Date(.y) - 1) %>% 
                               slice(1) %>% 
                               pull(adjusted)) %>% 
           as.numeric()) 

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  symbol company_name         date.filed price_before_filing
  <chr>  <chr>                <date>                   <dbl>
1 A      Agilent_Technologies 2020-12-18               118. 
2 A      Agilent_Technologies 2019-12-19                81.9
3 A      Agilent_Technologies 2021-12-17               150. 
4 AA     Alcoa                2020-02-21                16.0
5 AA     Alcoa                2019-02-26                30.6
6 AA     Alcoa                2021-02-25                27.1
```